# Does anyone recognize this q-expansion?

Tags: modular-forms, nt.number-theory

Consider the space of weight 1 modular forms for $\Gamma_{1}(7)$. A basis element of this dimension 3 space is $$f(q) = q - q^{3} + 2q^{4} + 2q^{5} - 3q^{6} + q^{7} + 3q^{8} - 2q^{9} - q^{10} + \cdots .$$
Does anyone recognize this as some product/division of eta functions? The command to generate a basis for the above mentioned modular forms is `ModularForms(Gamma1(7), 1).basis()`. The $f(q)$ above is the second element in the basis that is output.

Comment: Looks like what you have is a product not of eta functions but of Klein forms, which is almost as good.  It's $q\prod_{n=1}^\infty (1-q^n)^{c_n}$ where
$c_n = 2,0,1,-2$ according as $n \equiv 0, \pm 1, \pm 2, \pm 3 \bmod 7$.
cf. the formulas on p.84 of my chapter "The Klein Quartic in Number Theory"
= http://library.msri.org/books/Book35/files/elkies.pdf in
*The Eightfold Way: The Beauty of Klein's Quartic Curve*
= http://library.msri.org/books/Book35/contents.html .


Comment: P.S. To reproduce the computation "ModularForms(Gamma1(7), 1).basis()",  run that command in **Sage**.


Comment: @Noam Elkies: This will actually do, thank you! (On another note, how should I accept your comment as an answer?)